# How to represent hypothesis function in logistic regression cost function

Tags: math, machine-learning, symbolic-math, logistic-regression

Below is logistic regression cost function with features(x) , training examples(y)

[image]

How should the hypotheses function (circled red) be represented ? : [image]

I'm attempting to implement this function but unsure what value (or function) the hypothesis should take ?

Comment: The title is misleading because it mentions **linear** regression, but the cost function you shared is really for **logistic** regression. Which one is it?

Comment: @karlphillip question updated, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The activation function in logistic regression is the *sigmoid function* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sigmoid_function), defined as

[image]

which is also probability of y taking on a 1 value for a given x and parameter theta's to be determined (sigmoid is always between 0 and 1)

The cost function you mentioned comes from *maximum likelihood estimation* (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maximum_likelihood) of training (X, y) pairs. The log-likelihood of any (X, y) pair is exactly

[image]

The final loss function is precisely the sum of all log-likelihood for all `(X, y)` training pairs.

Thus, the ''hypothesis" you are talking about is simply sigmoid, `1/(1+exp(-theta * x))` (actually I am not familiar with the term hypothesis used in this context, but the expression resembles any standard expression involving sigmoid and MLE)

Comment: x's should be your input features (arrays like [4, 8, 1]) and thetas are the unknown parameters to be estimated. i.e., your code should create symbolic expressions involving thetas (x and y will take concrete values like [4, 8, 1]) use some optimization programs to minimize them.

Comment: should initial theta's not be randomized (or is this what you mean by "symbolic expressions involving thetas") and these theta values will change over the course of the ML algorithm as it tries to minimize them ? ref : https://www.quora.com/What-is-theta-in-machine-learning-From-where-do-we-get-theta-to-provide-to-any-machine-learning-algorithm

Comment: Yes, you start with some initial estimates of thetas and try to iteratively and systematically change them to minimize the objective function. Stochastic-Gradient-Descent (SGD) is a classic algorithm to do that. Most of the optimizers today perform this iterative optimization for you

Comment: Ok, so GD or SGD is used to minimize the values for theta ?